# Multi-File org-babel Projects?

Tags: org-babel

I'm attempting to use org-babel to do literate and meta-programming, but running into very puzzling limitations. I have numerous files that need similar functionality, so naturally, I'd like to factor this out into separate "library" files. Unfortunately, I cannot get any non-trivial org-babel code split into more than one file to work.

1. The first annoyance is that I can't find an org-babel equivalent of a way of loading a library. Every language I've ever used has such directives, typically called "include", "load", "use", "import", etc., but there doesn't seem to be an org-babel equivalent.

It is possible, though inelegant and awkward, to call code by placing an explicit path to the file where the source block is contained, such as

```
<</Users/joeschmoe/dev/babel/lib.org:my-func()>>
```

2. The second, bigger problem is that I don't know how to control the time and context of the computations. For instance,

   <lib.org:my-func(name=(buffer-file-name))>
   evaluates buffer-file-name in lib.org, not in the file it is called from. Most languages have, at the least, a distinction between immediate and delayed evaluation of passed arguments. I don't see that in org-babel.
3. The third, related problem, is that variables cannot be passed in arguments, because the org-babel looks in the file where the called code resides for the definition of the variable. So

```
#+name: myval
: 3
<<lib.org:myfunc<<name=myval>>
```

returns an error, because myval is defined in the file calling, rather than in lib.org.

I've looked around online and am hard pressed to find more than 2 or 3 trivial examples of multi-file org-babel code. For that matter, it's hard to find non-trivial examples of single-file org-babel. I have no sense of how active use and development of org-babel is.

Any suggestions how to procede?

Also, someone told me that Microsoft is working on a counterpart to org and org-babel that it is incorporating into VS Code. I haven't confirmed this. I'd appreciate if anyone can comment.

Comment: Check "Library of Babel" in both the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Library-of-Babel.html) and on [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/library-of-babel.org). It might help a bit with some of these problems, but I haven't really used it much, so I'm not sure.